# Cannot initialize PrintWriter field in constructor of a Thread

Tags: java

There is need to create a new thread for each connection. Thread should have function to write to socket even if it is in run() waiting for client input: `String clientCommand = in.readLine()`. The function `update` should meet this requirements and be able to write to socket using `PrintWriter outWr` but it seems to be `null`, even if setting it in thread constructor.
Cannot initialize `PrintWriter outWr` in constructor. After `try` construction `outWr` remains to be `null`. How to fix it?

---

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ...
        ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++, auction);
        ...
}
```

---

```
public class ClientServiceThread extends Thread  {
private PrintWriter outWr;

ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int clientID, Auction a) {
        try {
            PrintWriter outWr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    m_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void run() {....; String clientCommand = in.readLine(); ... }
public void update(String msg){outWr.println(msg);}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this code

```
public class ClientServiceThread extends Thread  {
private PrintWriter outWr;

ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int clientID, Auction a) {
        try {
            PrintWriter outWr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
```

In constructor you do not initialize class field but local reference `PrintWriter outWr`

Change it to

```
        try {
            outWr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
```